# MqttService issue when I publish message to server

Tags: protocol-buffers, mqtt

I'm using https://github.com/dirkmoors/MqttService as a android MQTT client to communicate with my MQTT server.

I published my message A(Protobuf payload) to my MQTT server. but I didn't get the related correct response message B(Protobuf payload).

Instead, I got the A in the `handleMessage(String topic, byte[] payload)` after I published message A without any error. I couldn't figure it out what happened. Could anyone please give me some hints?

Comment: You need to describe the problem a little more. Are you publishing and subscribing to the same topic?

Comment: Did you setup another client to actually generate the response message B?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I didn't subscribe the same topic, right now I can get the response, but also get the message A. it seems topic x was subscribed automatically after I published message to it.